# Route user to another HTML page using $state.go in Ionic

Tags: html, angularjs, routes, ionic-framework

I am creating a simple 'phonebook' test application and am running into an issue when attempting to navigate the user to a new page when clicking on an ion-item in and ion-list.

To give a brief overview of what I am trying to accomplish:

I have a SQLite DB that consists of information of users (name, phone number, etc)

I have created a ion-list to display all the users. When a user is clicked, it must direct the user to a new page that will go into a more in-depth description of all the users' information. Going from the 'home' page to the 'detail' page is where my problem lies. There is no error being thrown when clicking on the ion-item that contains the 'short description' of the user's information.

In my app.js file I have the following config:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider.state('home', {
          url: "/home",
          templateUrl: "index.html",
          controller: "HomeCtrl"
    })
    $stateProvider.state('detail', {
          url: "/detail",
          templateUrl: "dummy.html",
          controller: "DetailCtrl"
     })    
   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
 })

 .controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
    $scope.changeState = function () {
        console.log("home");
        $state.go('home');
    }
 })
 .controller('DetailCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
    $scope.changeState = function () {
        console.log("detail");
        $state.go('detail');
    }

 })
```

In my index.html, I have the following body:

```
  <ion-nav-view name="home" ui-sref="home"> 
    <ion-pane>
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-assertive">
            <h1 class="title">Contacts</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>

        <ion-content class="scroll-content" ng-controller="HomeScreenController" padding="true">

            <ion-list>
                <ion-item 
                    class="ion-item-content"      
                    ng-repeat="employee in allEmployeeInformation | orderBy:'lastName'"
                    ng-controller="DetailCtrl"
                    ng-click="changeState()">

                <div class="item-icon-left">
                    <i class="icon ion-person"></i>
                    <h3>{{employee.userCN}}</h3>
                    <h5>{{employee.title}}</h5>
                    <h6>{{employee.town}}</h6>
                </div>

                <div class="item-icon-right">
                    <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
                </div>

                </ion-item>
            </ion-list> 
        </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
 </ion-nav-view>
```

Not that this applies but just to be as thorough as possible, I'm currently just using a filler for the 'detail' page until I get this working. This contains the following:

```
<body ng-app="starter">
  <ion-nav-view name="detail" ui-sref="detail"> 
        <h1>John Doe</h1>
        <p>Developer</p>
 </ion-nav-view>
```

What would cause the click on the ion-item to (what appears to) not do anything? What am I missing that would make the user able to click the ion-item to navigate to the 'detail' HTML page?

I can provide any further information needed. I'm not sure how to continue at this point.

Thanks in advance for the help, guys.

Cheers,

-Mike

Answer (score 0):

@Michael I am working on ionic app that deals with routing using $state.go()

1. Inject $state service in your controller.

Sample App.js

```
.state('tab.chats', {
      url: '/chats',
      views: {
        'tab-chats': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-chats.html',
          controller: 'ChatsCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
```

Controller redirection logic

```
$state.go('tab.chats');
```

**Update - 4/2/2016**

Hey Michael thanks to your question now even i know how tab project is wired.. :)

This is working code. In your code you forgot to add abstract state which is parent state. see in my code **tab** state. where tab is parent state and [Parent]tab.home[child] and [Parent]tab.detail[child] states.

Create tabs project so you dont have to create all files from scratch. Tabs projects will allow you to create very structured project.

**Tabs.html**

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive">

  <!-- Home Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Status" icon-off="ion-ios-pulse" icon-on="ion-ios-pulse-strong" href="#/tab/home">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-home"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <!-- Detail Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Chats" icon-off="ion-ios-chatboxes-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-chatboxes" href="#/tab/detail">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-detail"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

**App.js**

```
// setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
 .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
  })

.state('tab.home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
      'tab-home': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('tab.detail', {
    url: '/detail',
    views: {
      'tab-detail': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-detail.html',
        controller: 'DetailCtrl'
      }
    }
  });
```

**Controller.js**

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope) {})

.controller('DetailCtrl', function($scope) {})
```

Create 2 html pages in template folder tab-home.html and tab-detail.html

I hope it resolves your bug.

Comment: Hi @Vaibhav, thanks for the response. Unless I am misunderstanding... ".controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, $state)" should be injecting the $state service into my controller. Is this correct?

Comment: you are injecting $state service correctly. I would suggest you to create tabs project first and edit it according to your requirement and check if you are able to redirect.

Comment: I am able to redirect to other view using <a href="#/tab/dash" class="button">Back to Listings</a>

Comment: I originally thought the tab project would be a good starting point, but our Business Owner who requested the app only wanted a single page. I'll take a look at this option and report back on my results.